# How to change the application from free to paid after some duration

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, whatsapp

I am doing one application.Now i want to give as free app,and after one year from installed date i need to change that one to paid app.Means i have to put the IAP subscription after one year completed.Like as What'app,that one also free one year from installed date onwards,next it become to new.i want to do my application.How can i do like that.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do that.
For that you need to have your own server where you have to save the user details and installation date. So when the user opens the app next time you have to check whether one year completed or not.
If completed you have to show your one year subscription ends and further use of this app you have to in-app purchase. From there user can pay if he want to use the app further.

Comment: But how can i identify which receipt belongs to which user in server side

Comment: each user is identified by unique identifier, if we take case of whats app each user has profile entry corresponding to each user, so when you request for this check you will pass the user id. and server will check the installation time corresponding to that user id.

Comment: But i don't want the user to complete the registration.Just install the app,after one week need to subscribe.ANd server will store the receipt.At storing time,what is the unique identifier to store the receipt.Is there any way to get the unique idnetifier from apple server with validation response.

Comment: ok, you will save the installation time on server, when time completed you can show the alert for in-app purchase, If this purchase is non-consumable Apple will store this information, once purchased you can update your app.

Comment: How can i identify which time belongs to which user?

Comment: you can save the time on local in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

On you first time launch you can save the datetimestamp in NSUserdefaults and everytime the  app is launched check for the diff between the saved date and the current date. If it is equal to or exceeds 1 year (or whatever time interval) block the features you want and redirect the user to a screen which will ask him to purchace the app or app feature.

If your app has a server side. You can check for this logic from the server side.

Comment: But how can i identify which receipt belongs to which user in server side